# Ranges with Linq and dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've created a Range type:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public Range(T min, T max) : this(min, max, false) { }
    public Range(T min, T max, bool upperbound)
    {
    }
    public bool Upperbound { get; private set; }
    public T Min { get; private set; }
    public T Max { get; private set; }
    public bool Between(T Value)
    {
        return Upperbound ? (Min.CompareTo(Value) < 0) && (Value.CompareTo(Max) <= 0) : (Min.CompareTo(Value) <= 0) && (Value.CompareTo(Max) < 0);
    }
}
```

I want to use this as key in a dictionary, to allow me to do a search based upon a range. And yes, ranges can overlap or there might be gaps, which is part of the design. It looks simple but I want the search to be even a bit easier! I want to compare a range with it's value of type T, so I can use: myRange == 10 instead of myRange.Between(10).

How? :-)
(Not wanting to break my head over this. I'll probably find the answer but maybe I'm re-inventing the wheel or whatever.)

---

The things I want to do with this dictionary? Well, in general I will use the range itself as a key. A range will be used for more than just a dictionary. I'm dealing with lots of data that have a min/max range and I need to group these together based on the same min/max values. The value in the dictionary is a list of these products that all have the same range. And by using a range, I can quickly find the proper list where I need to add a product. (Or create a new entry if no list is found.)

Once I have a list of products grouped by ranges, I can start searching for values that fir within specific ranges. Basically, this could be a Linq query on the dictionary of all values where the provides value is between the Min and Max value.

I am actually dealing with two such lists. In one, the range is upper-bound and the other lower-bound. There could be more of these kinds of lists, where I first need to collect data based on their range and then find specific items within them.

Could I use a List instead? Probably, but then I would not have the distinct grouping of my data based on the range itself. A List of Lists then? Possible, but then I'm considering the Dictionary again. :-)

---

Range examples: I have multiple items where the range is 0 to 100. Other items where range is 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc. More items where range is 0 to 4, 4 to 6, 6 to 8, etc. I even have items with ranges from 0 to 0.5, 0.5 to 1, 1 to 1.5, etc. So, first I will group all items based on their ranges, so all items with range 1 to 2 would be together in one list, while all items with range 0 to 100 would be in a different list. I've calculated that I'll be dealing with about 50 different ranges which can overlap each other. However, I have over 25000 items which need to be grouped like this.

Next, I get a value from another source. For example the value 1.12 which I need to find. So this time I use Linq to search through the dictionary to find all lists of items where 1.12 would be in the range of the keys. Thus I'd find the range 1 to 2, 1 to 1.5 and even 0 to 100. Behind these ranges there would be lists of items which I need to process for this value. And then I can move onwards to the next value, for about 4000 different values. And preferably everything should finish with 5 seconds.

Comment: If your ranges overlap, that means a value can be in two ranges at the same time, no? In that case using a Dictionary is not really an option... at least not the Dictionary(TKey,TValue) in System.Collections.Generic.

Comment: Unless you merge the overlapping ranges first...

Comment: Yes, two ranges can overlap. But I want to search on either an exact range or do a foreach to find any items where the specified value is within the range. But generally, I would search for exact ranges.

Comment: I don't fully understand what operations you intend to perform on this thing, but I suspect that dictionary and list are not the right data structures. Usually when dealing with ranges one constructs an interval tree. Perhaps that's the data structure you want?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: Generally, two operations: first collect information by grouping on range. (Identical min/max values. Then searching for the items where a value is within the related range. An interval tree could be useful but I would need to implement it first. (Can't use third-party code for this project.) It might not be the right structure but it's closest to what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a key in a dictionary is a matter of overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. Basically you'd create a hash based on the minimum and maximum values and Upperbound. Typically you call `GetHashCode` on each component and combine them, e.g.:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int result = 17;
    result = result * 31 + Min.GetHashCode();
    result = result * 31 + Max.GetHashCode();
    result = result * 31 + Upperbound ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You'd also need the equality test.

I'm not sure what you mean by "to allow me to do a search based upon a range" though. Could you give some sample code showing how you'd like to use this ability? I'm not entirely sure it'll fit within the normal dictionary approach...

I suggest you *don't* overload the == operator to allow you to do a containment test with it though. A range *isn't* equal to a value in the range, so code using that wouldn't be very intuitive.

(I'd personally rename `Between` to `Contains` as well.)

Comment: Overriding == operator is not even an option because both operands need to be of the same type.

Comment: @darin: No they don't. (It's overloading, not overriding btw.) I've just compiled code with `public static bool operator==(Test x, string y)` with no problems.

Comment: Jon is right; abusing equality in this way is weird. It is nice if you have equality operators that match our intuition as to how equality behaves. Like, A == B, B == C implies A == C, which I do not think is true in the "range" example.

Comment: Nope, if A and C are integers and B is a range of integers then even though A==B and B==C, A would not be equal to C.

Comment: @Workshop Alex: That's exactly the problem - your idea of equality goes against the intuitive sort of equality, so is a bad fit for it.